# How to call custom link by clicking button from datatable ColumnProperty in nopcommerce 4.3

Tags: javascript, url, datatable, controller, nopcommerce

I want to call link from **datatable ColumnProperty**, by clicking on button or any url in **nopcommerce 4.3**.

Here is my **Datatable** code,

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("Table", new DataTablesModel
{
    Name = "customerjama-grid",
    Length = Model.CustomerJamaSearchModel.PageSize,
    LengthMenu = Model.CustomerJamaSearchModel.AvailablePageSizes,                      
    ColumnCollection = new List<ColumnProperty>
    {
        new ColumnProperty(nameof(CustomerJamaModel.Date))
            {
                Title = T("Admin.Customer.Jama.Fields.Date").Text,
                Width = "200"
            },
        new ColumnProperty(nameof(CustomerJamaModel.Id))
        {
            Title = T("Admin.Common.PDF").Text,
            Width = "100",                        
            ClassName = NopColumnClassDefaults.Button,
            Render = new RenderCustom("CallController"),
        }
    }
})
```

Now, for that I am using **RenderCustom** property of **datatable**, but problem is that **"CallController"** in **RenderCustom** call the **javascript** **CallController** function when **page load**.

But my requirement is that when **I** click on the link related their **controller/javascript url** should be **fired**.

Comment: Can you please share the CallController js code?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly you can use in script:

```
      function CallController(data, type, row, meta) 
{
    return '<button onclick="javascript:window.location.href='+ yourlink + '
    ?id=' + data + '; return false;" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-print"></i>@T("Admin.Common.PDF")</button>';
};
```

Or if you want to use your own controller and action use:

```
 function CallController(data, type, row, meta) 
{
    return '<button onclick="javascript:window.location.href=
    ' + @Url.Action("yourAction", "yourController") + '?id=' + data + ';
    return false;" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-print"></i>@T("Admin.Common.PDF")</button>';
};
```

Please check for ' and "